# What is the equivalent of WKInterfaceController.didAppear() in SwiftUI on watchOS?

Tags: swiftui, watchos

I'm building an Apple Watch app, and there is code I want to run every time the app is brought to the foreground.

Previously, if I wanted to do this in a watchOS with a `WKInterfaceController`, I would put this code in `didAppear()`.

In SwiftUI, there is `onAppear()`, but when I call that on watchOS it only seems to be called the first time the app loads up, so it behaves like `WKInterfaceController.willActivate()` instead. The app has just a single view.

**If `onAppear()` is the equivalent  of `WKInterfaceController.willActivate()`, is there a different SwiftUI function that is the equivalent of `WKInterfaceController.didAppear()`?**

Here's my current example code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

        Text("Hello World").font(.footnote)
            .onAppear {
                print("onAppear called")
        }
    }
}
```

In the meantime, I am going to experiment with triggering what I need to do within the `ExtensionDelegate`, but I'm just trying to learn my way around SwiftUI on WatchOS, so knowing the answer to this would be helpful in the future.

Comment: As far as I understand and have experienced, didDeactivate is called whenever the app is backgrounded, or when the screen turns off while the app is in the foreground. willActivate is called whenever the app is brought into the foreground or when the screen is woken while the app is already in the foreground. It doesn't mean the controller is actually visible though, because it could be in a list of pages etc.